# Efficient way of vertically expanding a Dataframe by row and keeping the same values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing this educational challenge on kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales

The training set is a file of daily sales numbers of some products and the test set we need to predict is the sales of similar items for the month of november.
Now I would like to use my model to make daily predictions and thus expand the test data set by 30 for each row.
I have the following code:

```
for row in test.itertuples():
    df = pd.DataFrame(index = nov15, columns = test.columns)
    df['shop_id'] = row.shop_id
    df['item_category_id'] = row.item_category_id
    df['item_price'] = row.item_price
    df['item_id'] = row.item_id
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ['date', 'item_id', 'shop_id', 'item_category_id', 'item_price']
    df = df[train.columns]
    tt = pd.concat([tt, df])
```

`nov15` is a pandas daterange from 1/nov/2015 to 30/nov/2015

`tt` is just an empty dataset I fill by expanding it by 30 rows (nov 1 to 30) for every row in the test set.

`test` is the original dataframe I am copying the rows from

It runs, but it takes hours to complete.
Knowing pandas and learning from previous experiences, there is probably an efficient way to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to achieve, but could you post a before and after of some sample data to help clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a "more" efficient way, and then someone over at Reddit's r/learnpython has told me about the correct and most efficient way.
This above dilemma is easily solved by pandas [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function.

And these two lines do what I did above, but within seconds:

```
test['date'] = [nov15 for _ in range(len(test))]
test = test.explode('date')
```

Now my more efficient way or second solution, which is in no way anywhere close to equivalent or good was to simply make 30 copies of the dataframe with a column 'date' added.